# How to create one object with two or more constructor initialization at once

Tags: c++, c++17

How do we create one object with two or more constructor initialization at once, 
without changing all overload constructors and other existing codes? (Or if not at all, as least as change possible )

```
class valuation {
public:
    valuation(const int s) : pos(s) {};
    valuation(int a,int b,int c) : j(a),k(b),l(c) {};

private:    
    const int pos;
    int j,k,l;


main(){

  int a=1,b=2,c=3, v=7;

// how to set pos=7 j=1 k=2 l=3 once, below just illustration

  valuation O(v)      // ? 
  valuation O(a,b,c); // ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two constructors, neither of which initializes the object completely?

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. You have to create another constructor, if you need to construct the object in this fashion.

Comment: Multiple declaration of variable O.

Comment: Why not create a constructor taking all 4 parameters?

Comment: Given your previous question, I think some of the things you want are indicative of an XY problem. You're trying to do something, and you think that constructing the object twice is the way to do that thing. It almost certainly isn't, and there's a better solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ^ so the question is: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ cannot represent the concept of two-phase construction at a language level. By fiat, if an object's constructor completes, then it is a live object. And this means all of its sub-objects have already been constructed (and either initialized or left uninitialized). You could create a new object in its storage, but that would *overwrite* the old one, causing it to end its lifetime.

You can have a constructor defer primary construction to another constructor. But in doing so, that other constructor will properly construct the object. And even then, that's an implementation detail; it's not something that appears in the interface of the object.

You can initialize the `const` part of your object in your constructor and have a function to initialize the other subobjects. But as far as the language is concerned, that won't be any different from any other function call that manipulates the object members.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in C++.
Just create a constructor with 4 parameters, or add Setter in your class and set values.